# Function returning value with no specified return statement in the control flow structure

Tags: c, recursion, return

Today I was experimenting with random C code and I found something that confused me. In the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int x)
{
        if(x==2)
        return 2;
        else
        {
                printf("+");
                f(x-1);
        }
}
int main()
{
        int n,i;
        n = f(6);
        printf("%d\n",n);
}
```

The output is quite expectedly `++++2`, there is no confusion about the number of '+' because the number of recursive calls is 4. But my question is about the return value 2. In the function, a value is returned when the `if(x==2)` condition holds. Now when the function is being called with numbers other than 2, it will enter the `else` block. There is no explicit return statement in that block. But still it is returning a value. How is it allowed? How is the program deciding to return a number even when it is not explicitly told to do so? Is it that the program is simply returning the number it obtained from the recent function call? When a function is called, the caller maintains a stack. The return value is stored in a register. Is the function supposed to return the value stored in that register? Someone please explain it.

Comment: The compiler should warn you about not supplying a return value.  Try `-Wall` or similar for your compiler.  The value returned in this case is undefined and may appear to be "random".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `}` that terminates the function is reached, and the returned value is used in the caller, the behavior of the program is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You cannot expected any reasoning for the value *you* got as return. In another run, it may return a completely different integer value, return the complete lyrics of your favorite song, or set your computer on fire. Nothing is guaranteed.

Quoting C11, chapter §6.9.1

> *If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: I think it is returning the value obtained from most recent function call. Because when I am creating a dummy function like `int foo() {return 20;}`, and calling it after f(x-1), it is actually returning 20.

Comment: @Ricky As I said, it might be true for your case, but in general, this code is invalid as per the C standard,

Comment: Yes... the code is invalid. That's why the result surprised me!

Comment: @Ricky the result is undefined, but in practice the result is usually some leftover value in a register or in some memory location from previous operations, therefore it is not astonishing that you get 20 as result.

Comment: It has been observed elsewhere that, for a function that returns by reaching its close `}`, GCC may intentionally return the value of the last expression evaluated.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: “Undefined” in the C standard does not mean “invalid.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, it does not, but don't you say any code containing statements / expressions causing UB is invalid?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: No, definitely not. The C standard is written for the core C language to be extended. Some of those extensions are achieved by C implementations defining behavior that the C standard does not. Programs that use those are extensions and are accepted by a C implementation are, as defined by the C standard, *conforming* but not *strictly conforming*. They are not invalid, and the notion that “undefined behavior” is automatically invalid is a misunderstanding of the C standard.